# When will an interactively typed backspace be passed as input?

Tags: tty, control-characters

I just noticed that I've seen different behavior across different systems when creating a quick test file (e.g. with sample input) via `cat` and redirection.

Here are the steps to see what I'm talking about:

Run `cat > testfile`.

Type in `helli`, then press backspace, then type `o`.

Press Enter.

Type Ctrl-D to end the input.

Run `od -a testfile`.

On some systems, e.g. Mac, you will get:

```
0000000    h   e   l   l   o  nl                                        
0000006
```

On other systems, e.g. a RHEL 5.7 host that I logged into via MobaXterm on Windows, you may get:

```
0000000    h   e   l   l   i  bs   o  nl                                        
0000010
```

Where is the code that makes for this difference?  For example, in the example above, should I suspect MobaXterm, or the RHEL 5 system?  Or which layer between my keyboard and the filesystem?

---

This is more a question out of curiosity than a real problem; I can obviously create files without the backspace characters by just using a text editor, but this has tripped me up in the past.  One time during a casual presentation/training, I mentioned that creating files via `cat` has this problem with backspace characters being taken literally, only to be shown wrong when it didn't have that effect after all, *on the Macs the students were using.*  So it got me curious.

Answer (score 4):

That's determined by a) what characters does the terminal emulator send when the BackSpace key is pressed (`^H`/`BS` or `^?`/`DEL`) and b) what character is used as `VERASE` by the tty driver (see and change the latter with `stty(1)` -- `stty erase ^H`).

If the terminal emulator is sending `^H` but the tty isn't recognizing it as a special character, presssing the BackSpace key will visually "erase" the last character on the screen[1], but the character will be sent as-is (together with the character before it) to the process reading from the tty (`cat`).

Editors and interactive programs with line-editing capabilities set the tty to raw mode and do their own handling of special characters, and may treat `^H` and `^?` the same; `cat` isn't one of those ;-)

[1] this is subject to the `echoctl` `stty` setting -- if that is set, the terminal will echo control characters back in the `"^"+chr(char^0x40)` format (`^H` for `BS = 8`, etc).

Answer (score 1):

You can reproduce the behavior you are seeing with `cat` by manipulating the terminal characteristics of your shell with the `stty` command.

When the terminal is in canonical mode, input is gathered into lines, line editing is enabled and optionally stdin is echoed to the screen (IEXTEN flag).

In non-canonical mode some control characters are passed on to the shell.

Example:

```
stty -icanon
cat > testfile # end with ctrl-c
#typed ls | space | backspace | ctrl-h | al | ctrl-d | ctrl-c
od -a testfile
0000000   l   s  sp del  bs   a   l  nl eot
0000011
```

To resume canonical mode:

```
stty icanon
```

To interrogate the current terminal device:

```
stty
# OR for more info
stty -a
speed 9600 baud; rows 62; columns 255; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = M-^?; eol2 = M-^?; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; discard = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd -cmspar cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff -iuclc -ixany imaxbel iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt echoctl echoke -flusho -extproc
```

The output of the flags section of this command is such that a preceeding `-` indicates that a flag is unset, so `icanon` is on and `-icanon` is off for the canonical flag.

From the man page:

> Optional - before SETTING indicates negation.  An * marks non-POSIX settings.

Comment: You are conflating pseudo-terminals and line disciplines.

Comment: @JdeBP A fair and enlightening critique.